File not being written to
I am working on a website with django and am currently trying to add a way for users to upload a file to the website and just to test have it write to my pc.
But the problem is that nothing is being written to my desktop. I am not getting any errors just nothing is being written. The file I am testing with is a jpeg.
The function:
def download_file(filename):
    with open(r'C:\Users\kenco\OneDrive\Desktop\file.jpg', 'wb+') as destination:
        destination.write(filename)

The django view:
def file_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = file_uploader(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            download_file(filename=request.FILES['file'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success')
    else:
        form = file_uploader()

    return render(request, 'home_page.html', {'form' : form})

The form:
from django import forms    

class file_uploader(forms.Form):
    question = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = forms.FileField()

I tried to just write to desktop and it didnt work. I tried to do the string without a r string. And I tried to write it without the .jpg
This code is also based around the django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/topics/http/file-uploads/

The file is only written if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid().  Are you sure both of those are true?

I think so but I don't know how to check. On the html file the method is post. And when I enter the file and question it doesnt tell me i need to change it or anything

I think you can add print statements inside the if blocks, so you can see the output and know which path the code takes.

What response is returned to the browser?  Is it return HttpResponseRedirect('/success') or is it return render(request, 'home_page.html', {'form' : form}) ?

It does not return me to /success i just stay at the same url. I also added print statements but nothing is being returned to the terminal. Where do I look for the print statements

The print statements should be in the webserver log output.

If the browser does not go to the success page, then that means your download function is not even being called.

Yeah nothing is being returned to the terminal

What can I do to fix that?

Nothing is being printed to the terminal at all even though I have print statements in the downloadfile functions and the view

You said the browser is not returning to the success page, which means the download_file function is not being called at all.  So putting print statements inside that function is useless.

Please update the question to show exactly where you added the print statements in the view function.

I found an answer
There was a problem with my urls
Basically the form was being showed but the view not being called because of a mix-up with urls
It went from:


urlpatterns= [
    path('home/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="home_page.html"), name='home_page'),
    path('forms/', views.file_form, name='file_form')
] 

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="home_page.html"), name='home_page'),
    path('file/', include('home.urls'))
]



To:


urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="home_page.html"), name='home_page'),
    path('forms/', views.file_form, name='file_form'),
]

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('home.urls')),
]



